# std::execution breaks file writing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing, c++17, ofstream

The program seems to exit without waiting for the file system to apply the inner changes when integrating with `std::execution`.

I recently tried PPL, TBB, OpenMP and `std::exection` to find the fastest parallel lib for a particular work running on my machine. The work is to recursively convert some files into another form, which is basically:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

const auto CurrentPath = fs::current_path();

fs::path GetOutputPath(const fs::directory_entry& Entry)
{
    return CurrentPath / "Converted" / fs::relative(Entry, CurrentPath);
}

// Convert and save a file entry.
void ConvertFile(const fs::directory_entry& Entry)
{
    ifstream IStream(Entry.path(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    noskipws(IStream);

    ofstream OStream(GetOutputPath(Entry), ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

    // Read the data.
    // Intentional `uint8_t` for some special needs.
    vector<uint8_t> Data;
    Data.reserve(Entry.file_size());
    Data.assign(istream_iterator<uint8_t>(IStream), {});

    // Some changes to `Data`.
    // Left blank to simplify the problem.

    // Write to the output file.
    OStream.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Data[0]), Data.size());
}

// Convert and save a directory entry.
void ConvertDirectory(const fs::directory_entry& Entry);

// Convert and save an entry.
void Convert(const fs::directory_entry& Entry)
{
    // Recursively loop directories
    if (Entry.is_directory())
    {
        ConvertDirectory(Entry);
    }
    else
    {
        ConvertFile(Entry);
    }
}

void ConvertDirectory(const fs::directory_entry& Entry)
{
    // Not using `recursive_directory_iterator` since its order is not guaranteed.
    // I think manual recursion can always minimize the number of calls to create a directory.
    vector<fs::directory_entry> SubEntries(fs::directory_iterator(Entry), {});
    fs::create_directory(GetOutputPath(Entry));

    // ** Parallel ** part.
    for_each(SubEntries.cbegin(), SubEntries.cend(), Convert);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ConvertDirectory(fs::directory_entry(CurrentPath / "Test"));
}
```

With PPL (`ppl.h`), I change the `** Parallel ** part` to:

```cpp
    concurrency::parallel_for_each(SubEntries.cbegin(), SubEntries.cend(), Convert);
```

With TBB (`oneapi/tbb.h`):

```cpp
    tbb::parallel_for_each(SubEntries.cbegin(), SubEntries.cend(), Convert);
```

With `std::execution`:

```cpp
    for_each(execution::par, SubEntries.cbegin(), SubEntries.cend(), Convert);
```

Results:
**Test 1**: 700 files in 300 dirs, 1.5MB per file, avg values from 10 tests per cell
**Test 2**: 50k files in 5k dirs, 0.15MB per file, avg values from 20 tests per cell

|  | Test 1 | Test 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Original) | 2.8s | 130s |
| PPL | 0.59s | 37s |
| TBB | 0.58s | 36.8s |
| std::execution | 0.55s | 32.6s |

The improvements are quite obvious.
But the problem is, when I check the output files per test, I found the `std::execution` version may have as low as 45k output files in a test 2. If I print a message after each `write()`, the problem still exists, while the number of messages is always 50k, so every file is processed and the problem seems more likely to be the `write` calls not being fully applied to the file system when the program exits.

The number of directories is always correct, and the PPL and TBB versions don't have a such problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
Did I wrote anything wrong? What can I do to prevent this from happening with `std::execution`?

Comment: The program terminates normally or abruptly? (`std::terminate` called). I'd try to `flush` each write and see what happens. I'd also catch and log any exception that could be thrown in your convert functions.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use `par_unseq` here instead of just `par`? The former has stricter requirements on what standard library functions may be used (they must be vectorization-safe) and my feeling is that these IO functions are not.

Comment: @MatG The program terminates normally. I tried `flush` / `close` after each write, the benchmarks were almost the same and the problem is still there. I tried try-catch `ConvertFile` and the `main` functions, but no exception was caught. I also tried switching to use `std::copy` / `<<` to write the data, the number of lost files was somehow decreased per test, but still none of these changes had completely solved the problem.

Comment: @user17732522 By [this Microsoft post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/), the Visual C++ implementation implements `par` and `par_unseq` the same way, and in my practice changing it really didn't resolve the problem either. I picked `par_unseq` because the same post said that other implementations might make better optimization based on it, and I didn't find anything in my code that contradicted the requirements. I will change my description to clarify the issue.

Comment: "_which is basically_": Were you testing this _exact_ program (except for replacement of the `for_each` line and additional `#include`)? In particular, did you use a `std::vector` or a different container?

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I am testing this *exact* program, just except the replacement and that the source folder name `"Test"` is actually read from `argv[1]`. When timing, I include and use `std::chrono` in `main`, but the problem exists whether or not `std::chrono` is included.

Comment: @user17732522 This problem is particularly serious when the program is running in the background. When running in background, like now I am writing a comment in a browser, the PPL and TBB versions take more than twice as long to complete their work, while the `std::execution` version takes almost the same amount of time, except that it's losing more than half of the files. You can try that if you found it hard to reproduce.

Comment: @PaperStrike I can't actually reproduce it because I don't have a suitable system available at the moment, but I just asked since I noticed there was a bug in the Microsoft STL for the case that the iterator is _not_ a random-access iterator: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/commit/8a8e7cb719890899bf9b92bb78577d085c626b09. It could have been related if you weren't using `std::vector`.